# Transformar o texto de uma variável em um array

Tags: php

Estou utilizando php.

Possuo a seguinte texto numa variável:

```
X-Inquiry-Name: analia felices

X-Inquiry-Adults: 5

X-Inquiry-Children: 10
```

Gostaria de estar transformando em um array, separando esses dois pontos, mais ou menos como exemplo abaixo:

```
array (

[X-Inquiry-Name] => analia felices

[X-Inquiry-Adults] => 5

[X-Inquiry-Children] => 10

)
```

Tentei buscar uma função no http://php.net mas não consegui achar algo que faça isso. alguém lembra de alguma função para fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.
Consegui resolver de forma definitiva com o seguinte código:

```
preg_match_all('/([^: ]+): (.+?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', $emailStructure2, $match);
$newArray = array();
foreach($match[1] as $k => $value){
$newArray[$value] = $match[2][$k];
}echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

O que você basicamente tem um sua string é um padrão `X-Inquiry-`.
A função `preg_match_all` busca por todos os padrões presentes na string, de acordo com a regex passada.

```
preg_match_all('/(X-Inquiry-\w+):(.*)/', $str, $match);
// X-Inquiry- é seu padrão ele sempre deve procurar por isso
// \w+ busca por qualquer coisa que seja [a-zA-Z0-9_]
// (X-Inquiry-\w+) é um grupo de captura
// : deve capturar sempre 
// (.*) é o segundo grupo de captura que busca qualquer coisa

// $match terá o indice `1` representado pelo grupo 1
// e indice `2`  representado pelo grupo 2

$newArray = array();
// o foreach foi usado para unir os "match" em chave, valor
foreach($match[1] as $k => $value){
    $newArray[$value] = $match[2][$k];
}
```

Comment: Recomendo que explique o código, acaso o autor precise fazer alguma modificação em caso de outra necessidade, tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Boa noite Guilherme, Seu código deu certo, agora estou com uma dificuldade, em um dos itens esta aparecendo errado por dentro dele tem 2 dois pontos.

Entra assim: Subject: Contato de analia felices: de 10/01/16 ao 25/01/16 -

Sai assim: [Subject: Contato de analia felices] => de 10/01/16 ao 25/01/16 -

Comment: Opa, desculpe, meu script esta assim: 
preg_match_all('/(.*): (.*)/', $emailStructure2, $match);

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, já consegui.